# Can we setup CDC Tracking on a view or materialized view?

Tags: sql-server, debezium, confluent-platform

Can we setup CDC Tracking on a view or materialized view? We are using confluent platform, source is SQL Server & CDC tool is debezium.

Comment: Not sure why this question has been closed. It's clear what's being asked (can you use CDC tracking on views or VMs in SQL Server).

Answer (score 3):

Based on [About Change Data Capture (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) you can only define CDC against tables themselves.

> Change data capture records insert, update, and delete activity that is applied to a **SQL Server table**.

Comment: Thanks Robin, So we can't fetch data changes from a view in any condition?

Comment: @SamadAbbasi, unfortunately it’s impossible